# Accessing list of files within a Dropbox folder using php, basic environment without Dropbox sdk

Tags: php, dropbox

I am a very basic programmer, beginning a project in which I need to obtain the list of files within a Dropbox folder using PHP.

I am using a basic PHP Deverver 17 environment, with cURL enabled, PHP Version 5.6.30, allow_url_fopen=ON, allow_url_include=ON.

I always get a NULL at the $responseDdata.

```
<?php

// Replace with your own Dropbox API credentials
$accessToken = 'my_correct_accessToken';

// Specify the path of the Dropbox folder to browse
$folderPath = '/Dropbox/Apps/Folder/';

// Define the Dropbox API endpoint for listing folder contents
$apiEndpoint = 'https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/files/list_folder';

// Define the parameters for the API request
$params = array(
    'path' => $folderPath,
    'recursive' => false,
    'include_media_info' => false,
    'include_deleted' => false,
    'include_has_explicit_shared_members' => false
);

// Create a HTTP POST request to the Dropbox API endpoint
$ch = curl_init($apiEndpoint);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Authorization: Bearer ' . $accessToken,
    'Content-Type: application/json'
));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($params));

// Execute the API request and get the response
$response = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

// Parse the API response as JSON
$responseData = json_decode($response, true);

// Output the decoded API response
var_dump($responseData);

// Generate HTML output to display the PDF file links on a web page
$htmlOutput = '<h1>PDF Files in Dropbox Folder</h1>';
if (isset($responseData['entries']) && count($responseData['entries']) > 0) {
    $htmlOutput .= '<ul>';
    foreach ($responseData['entries'] as $entry) {
        if ($entry['.tag'] === 'file' && pathinfo($entry['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION) === 'pdf') {
            $fileName = $entry['name'];
            $fileId = $entry['id'];
            $htmlOutput .= '<li><a href="https://www.dropbox.com/s/' . $fileId . '?dl=1" target="_blank">' . $fileName . '</a></li>';
        }
    }
    $htmlOutput .= '</ul>';
} else {
    $htmlOutput .= '<p>No PDF files found in the specified folder.</p>';
}

// Output the HTML content
echo $htmlOutput;

?>
```

Comment: No excuse for using `PHP Version 5.6.30` its almost as old as Methuselah

Comment: Maybe show us an `echo $response;` as well